# Swap space extensively used while enough RAM is available on Ubuntu 20.04.01

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, swap

On a new dedicated root server with Ubuntu 20.04.01, running only MySQL 8.x the system starts to swap extensively while enough RAM is available.

System:

- RAM 230GB
- Swap space 64GB
- InoDB_Buffer set to 170GB
- AMD EPYC 7502
- Ubuntu 20.04.01
- Swapiness 0,10

[image]

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                  23G   16M   22G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg0-root   30G  3.6G   25G  13% /
tmpfs                 111G     0  111G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/md0              485M  251M  209M  55% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-data  393G  245G  129G  66% /mnt/data
/dev/mapper/vg0-tmp   5.0G   33M  5.0G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg0-home  200G   52G  149G  26% /home
tmpfs                  23G     0   23G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                  23G     0   23G   0% /run/user/1001
```

Only service running is MySQL with importing a large DB from MySQLdump (Table > 800M Datasets).

This does not happen on a smaller server with 128GB. Something seems to be misconfigured.

What could be the reason for swapping so extensively and how can this be fixed? It does not look like a stable system to me when swapping this much.

Comment: Where is it showing that `swap` is extensively used? For clarity, add the output of `free -gh` to the question.

Comment: You can see it in the graph, red. Was at about 10G

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`  -- on both servers.  What OS version was the smaller server using?  What was the buffer_pool_size on it?

Comment: How you define there is *enough ram"? Compare commited_as from /proc/meminfo with ram size

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Additional OS information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.